# Espresso Machine: How Old is Too Old?

Tags: espresso-machine

I inherited a Krups Type 964 espresso machine from my parents. Actually, I found it under a pile of junk in their garage 5 to 6 years ago. It had been under that pile of junk for probably more than 10 years. I cleaned it off and ran white vinegar through it a few times and it has worked mostly fine ever since. It can't push water through coffee that is too finely ground and it has a leaking overflow spigot (which I fixed with some flexible tubing). I've never used the milk frother.

Besides that it has consistently made 1 to 2 double shots of espresso for me everyday for the last 5 to 6 years.

What I am wondering is - at point should I just get a new espresso machine? Is there a chance this old one will violently rupture/explode due to use and age? Am I better off just investing in a new one?

Comment: My brand new Krups developed a leak inside a year. 3 times it went back to the manufacturer for 'fixing' before they replaced it. This one leaks differently, usually only when in the cleaning cycle, when it overflows the drip-tray... Long & short, use it til it fails. Enjoy the coffee, which it's pretty good at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to service the machine. Think of it as bringing your car to the shop or going to a physician / dentist yourself, so a professional can check some things that might be indicative of problems and do some basic maintenance.

You can try to find a (video) guide for your specific model, try it yourself (with or without a guide) or have it done by some shop.

Generally, you'll want to look for obvious problems like small leaks, rust and mould. Other things you might be able to do is replacing the gaskets that seal of different tubes. For that, you'd need to know which ones you need exactly.